# django-allauth: Only allow users from a specific google apps domain

Tags: django, django-allauth

I am a newbie at Django. Using django-allauth I have set up single click sign in. I obtained my domain credentials ( client_id and secret_key) from google api console. But the problem is django-allauth is **letting me login from any google account while I want the email addresses to be restricted to my domain** ( @example.com instead of @gmail.com)

django-social-auth has the white listed domains parameter for this, how do I include this information in allauth?
I found django-allauth much easier to set up after spending hours on django-social-auth

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Answering my own question-

What you want to do is stall the login after a user has been authenticated by a social account provider and before they can proceed to their profile page. You can do this with the

**pre_social_login**  method of the **DefaultSocialAccountAdapter** class in **allauth/socialaccount/adaptor.py**

> Invoked just after a user successfully authenticates via a
> social provider, but before the login is actually processed
> (and before the pre_social_login signal is emitted).
> You can use this hook to intervene, e.g. abort the login by
> raising an ImmediateHttpResponse
> Why both an adapter hook and the signal? Intervening in
> e.g. the flow from within a signal handler is bad -- multiple
> handlers may be active and are executed in undetermined order.

Do something like

```
from allauth.socialaccount.adaptor import DefaultSocialAccountAdapter

class MySocialAccount(DefaultSocialAccountAdapter):
    def pre_social_login(self, request, sociallogin):
        u = sociallogin.account.user
        if not u.email.split('@')[1] == "example.com"
            raise ImmediateHttpResponse(render_to_response('error.html'))
```

This is not an exact implementation but something like this works.

Comment: and after creating a custom adapter, register it with `settings.SOCIALACCOUNT_ADAPTER` as per the configuration section in the plugin's docs.

Comment: for future reference I found I had to use `u = sociallogin.user` otherwise I would get an error if the user did not previously exist.

Answer (score 4):

Here's an alternate solution:

```
from allauth.account.adapter import DefaultAccountAdapter
from allauth.socialaccount.adapter import DefaultSocialAccountAdapter

class CustomAccountAdapter(DefaultAccountAdapter):
    def is_open_for_signup(self, request):
        return False # No email/password signups allowed

class CustomSocialAccountAdapter(DefaultSocialAccountAdapter):
    def is_open_for_signup(self, request, sociallogin):
        u = sociallogin.user
        # Optionally, set as staff now as well.
        # This is useful if you are using this for the Django Admin login.
        # Be careful with the staff setting, as some providers don't verify
        # email address, so that could be considered a security flaw.
        #u.is_staff = u.email.split('@')[1] == "customdomain.com"
        return u.email.split('@')[1] == "customdomain.com"
```

This code can live anywhere, but assuming it's in `mysite/adapters.py`, you'll also need the following in your `settings.py`:

```
ACCOUNT_ADAPTER = 'mysite.adapters.CustomAccountAdapter'
SOCIALACCOUNT_ADAPTER = 'mysite.adapters.CustomSocialAccountAdapter'
```

Comment: I try this solution but I keep getting "Sign up is closed" from social account login. Already set `SOCIALACCOUNT_LOGIN_ON_GET = True` and `SOCIALACCOUNT_AUTO_SIGN_UP = True`

Answer (score 0):

You could do something in the line of overriding allauth's allauth.socialaccount.forms.SignupForm and checking the domain during the signup process.
Discalmer: this is all written without testing, but something in the line of that should work.

```
# settings.py
# not necesarry, but it would be a smart way to go instead of hardcoding it
ALLOWED_DOMAIN = 'example.com'
```

.

```
# forms.py
from django.conf import settings
from allauth.socialaccount.forms import SignupForm


class MySignupForm(SignupForm):

    def clean_email(self):
        data = self.cleaned_data['email']
        if data.split('@')[1].lower() == settings.ALLOWED_DOMAIN:
            raise forms.ValidationError(_(u'domena!'))
        return data
```

in your urls override allauth defaults (put this before the include of django-allauth)

```
# urls.py

from allauth.socialaccount.views import SignupView
from .forms import MySignupForm


urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # ...
    url(r"^social/signup/$", SignupView.as_view(form_class=MySignupForm), name="account_signup"),
    # ...
)
```

I'm not sure for the "^social/signup/$", recheck that.

Comment: The correct url is accounts/social/signup. But this doesn't work. I don't want to display an allauth Sign Up form after logging in with google. What I want is that immediately after google login, either they are directed to their profile pages or they get an error messsage saying-we only accept users from example.com domain.

Comment: Should I be using pre_social_login signal of django-allauth to to the domain matching?