# django-allauth - Critical login required : Allow users stored in a database only to login

Tags: django, django-allauth

I have implemented login form for username/password method, and that works perfect.

I want user to be also able to login using their social accounts.

I am using django-allauth to map social users to django-users.

Now I want to allow only those social accounts to login, that are mapped to django-users and not everyone.

Is there a way to override `callback view`? or something else can be done?

Comment: Can you simply disable registration, such that you have to create the account yourself and they later have to change their password? You can also disable registration but implement invitations. I can give details if this is a good solution

Comment: Yes, that sounds good. Please go ahead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally After reading the documents thoroughly and doing a lot of trials and errors I got to what I was looking for.

I had to set following parameters as a part of configuration specified in [docs](http://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html).

> ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED (=False)
>      The user is required to hand over an e-mail address when signing up.

and

> SOCIALACCOUNT_QUERY_EMAIL (=ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED)
>   Request e-mail address from 3rd party account provider? E.g. using OpenID AX, or the Facebook “email” permission.

I had to set `ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True` as it was required to check if that email id is already registerd with us.

and then finally I overridden `pre_social_login` like below.

```
from allauth.socialaccount.adapter import DefaultSocialAccountAdapter  

class NoNewSocialLogin(DefaultSocialAccountAdapter):

    def pre_social_login(self, request, sociallogin):
        try:
            cr_user = auth_user.objects.get(email=sociallogin.user.email)

            if cr_user and cr_user.is_active:
                user_login = login(request, cr_user, 'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend')
                raise ImmediateHttpResponse(HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('protect')))
            else:
                raise  ImmediateHttpResponse(render_to_response("account/authentication_error.html"))
        except ObjectDoesNotExist as e:
            raise ImmediateHttpResponse(render_to_response("socialaccount/authentication_error.html"))
        except Exception as e:
            raise ImmediateHttpResponse(HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('protect')))
```

Answer (score 1):

To simply disable registration, you have to overwrite the default account adaptor. If you also want to support social login, you also need to overwrite the default soculaaccount adapter. Add the following code somewhere in one of your apps (e.g. `adapter.py`):

```
from allauth.account.adapter import DefaultAccountAdapter
from allauth.socialaccount.adapter import DefaultSocialAccountAdapter
from allauth.exceptions import ImmediateHttpResponse

class NoNewUsersAccountAdapter(DefaultAccountAdapter):

    def is_open_for_signup(self, request):
        return False

class SocialAccountWhitelist(DefaultSocialAccountAdapter):

    def pre_social_login(self, request, sociallogin):
        u = sociallogin.user
        print('User {0} is trying to login'.format(u.email))
        # Write code here to check your whitelist
        if not_in_your_list(u):
            raise ImmediateHttpResponse(HttpResponseRedirect('/account/login'))
```

and then add the following to your settings:

```
ACCOUNT_ADAPTER = 'path_to_app.adapter.NoNewUsersAccountAdapter'
SOCIALACCOUNT_ADAPTER = 'path_to_app.adapters.SocialAccountWhitelist'
```

After that, all you need to do is manually create an Account from the Admin pages, and manually create an EmailAddress. For the social login, you will need to write code to somehow check if the email is allowed

I would recommend you add a Staff-Only form to make this easy on you, where you can ask for username, email (and even password) and then do

```
new_user = Account.objects.create_user(email=email, username=username, password=password)
EmailAddress.objects.create(email=email, user=new_user, verified=True, primary=True)
```

You can also develop an Invitation scheme, but that is a lot more complicated but quickly googled and found the following project, which I have not personally used, but looks like what you need:

https://github.com/bee-keeper/django-invitations

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This sounds promising. I shall try this soon. Yes, I have already developed a staff only form to create user.

Comment: This is unfortunately blocking all users, stored in database also.

Comment: any suggestions? What should I read or any example?
If not [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19232328/1936024) answer is my final resort.

Comment: What do you mean? Yes, this will block everybody from registering ( signing up ) but should have no effect on logging in

Comment: I hit 'account/login's URL it loads html where there is link to sign up and links to login for enabled aaps. I click on link for enabled apps. Which is URL for login.

Comment: What's an enabled app? Do you mean social login?

Comment: Yes, enabled social login.

Comment: Ok, you didn't mentioned you had social login enabled. You want the users that you are adding to have social login or a username and password?

Comment: And are you saying you no longer able to login with username and password? All we did was remove registration. Nothing else

Comment: I want my user to be able to login with username password and social auth also

Comment: Ok, my solution only deals with normal login ( please update your OP to mention the critical social login req). Need to look into the social issue but the solution is likely adding another special adapter for login

Comment: Oh... okay. Thanks for the help though

Comment: Added some code for the social login. see if it works.

Comment: Tried that already, `sociallogin.user` is empty for me. also `sociallogin.account.user` empty too.