# Django Allauth and G suite, how to handle multiple domains?

Tags: django, django-allauth, google-workspace

We are currently working on a Django CRUB style webapp where multiple 'tenants' each have their own 'members' (users linked to that tenant), 'Courses', etc.

We want to include a 'login with google' option and have thus turned to Django-allauth.  Most Tenants use Google G suit with their own `[name]@[tenant].com` address.

A user is assigned to their tenant after their account has been created, to prevent users of tenant B from creating a account in tenant A, we've included a function that checks if the domain of the email matches the 'domain' field in the Tenant object. Only if this match does indeed occur is the account created.

However recently one of our tenants has begun using more than 1 email domain which required us to update the code and Tenant Object. 
(Making the code handle multiple email domains, chancing the models so tenants can have multiple email domains)

This left us to wonder if there is a better way to do this - we've been investigating if Google provides a `company_id` response, or anything that would help us identify a company aside from their email domain. Those values could help us check if a users does indeed belong to that tenant, without having to constantly check / update email domain fields - but we've been unable to find anything of the sort.

Responses to [this similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19113623/django-allauth-only-allow-users-from-a-specific-google-apps-domain) stackoverflow question suggest a similar approach to the one we are currently taking, but that was five years ago - is this still truly the best way?

Comment: Would you mind sharing what you did to make django-allauth match the tenants domain?

Comment: @jasper Encountering similar issue here. Were you ever able to get a solution for this?